# Linkedin og:image, og:image:secure_url not being picked up when sharing secure site

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

(One of) the offending URLs: https://www.satelytics.com/resources/2016-edward-cheslak-of-pg-e-on-satelytics-amazing-insights

No matter what I try, I cannot get LinkedIn to display the og:image in shares. Only when I share this site without ssl (say, using vagrantshare) does it work. Anyone have any experience fixing this sort of thing?

Comment: Could you figure this out? I've been stuck on this issue for days now, just don't know what else to do. I've tried og:image:secure_url, og:image:url, og:image, but anything will make LinkedIn change its mind :(

Comment: I have not discovered a solution. I fired off an angry email. No luck.